# code signing for iOS release build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am just looking for an extra pair of eyes (well, expert review) on how my code signing should look in Xcode before I send a build to be reviewed for release. I am attaching an image below. Does it look correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Both Debug entries should use "iOS Developer" and both Release entries should use "iOS Distribution".